# I can not do pagination codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I'm having trouble doing pagination . I did var_dump and be all right . returns the right data . I think the problem is in my model . because I used other models and pagination is ok . how can I be missing ?

```
 <?php //pagination settings
           $config['base_url'] = site_url('contato/gerenciar');
           $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('msg');
           $config['per_page'] = "5";
           $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
           $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
           $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);

           //config for bootstrap pagination class integration
           $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
           $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
           $config['first_link'] = false;
           $config['last_link'] = false;
           $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
           $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
           $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
           $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
           $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
           $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
           $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
           $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
           $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
           $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
           $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
           $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
           $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
           $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';


           $this->pagination->initialize($config);
           $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

           //call the model function to get the department data
           $data['deptlist'] = $this->sindico->get_msg($config["per_page"], $data['page']); var_dump($this->sindico->get_msg());
           $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

           ?>
```

My modell

```
public function get_msg()
{   $msg = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('msg');
    $this->db->join ('usuarios u', 'u.id_usu = id_user_msg');
    $this->db->where('id_user_msg',$msg);

    $query = $this->db->get('');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: your get_msg does not have any parameters in it for limit and offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

load the pagination library first

```
$this->load->library("pagination");
```

in  model:

```
public function get_msg($limit, $offset)
{   
    $msg = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('msg');
    $this->db->join ('usuarios u', 'u.id_usu = id_user_msg');
    $this->db->where('id_user_msg',$msg);

   $query = $this->db->get('');
   return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Sindico_model::get_msg(), called in C:\wamp\www\edficio\application\controllers\contato.php on line 20 and defined

Filename: models/sindico_model.php